# PATH set manually is different from PATH displayed in JAVA

Tags: java, macos, terminal, path

I have set path manually in java(mac os)

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/libimobiledevice/HEAD-b78a42e/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

As you can see from the first image is have set **libimobiledevice** framework path in /etc/paths file in MAC machine.

But when I try to print the path in eclipse using Java code a different PATH variable is printed. Please have a look at console trace below:

```
JAVA_STARTED_ON_FIRST_THREAD_7021   1
SHELL   /bin/bash
JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_7228    org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG
TMPDIR  /var/folders/8m/wlsxm68n4_n8tj227658n35h0000gq/T/
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING 0x1F7:0x0:0x0
PATH    /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
APP_ICON_7021   ../Resources/Eclipse.icns
XPC_FLAGS   0x0
USER    labtest05
HOME    /Users/labtest05
LOGNAME labtest05
XPC_SERVICE_NAME    org.eclipse.platform.ide.126432
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render              /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.JLWxjCI7kr/Render
SSH_AUTH_SOCK   /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.gE42K76CP6/Listeners
```

Below is the Java code I wrote to display the path,

```
Map<String,String> map = System.getenv();
for(Entry<String, String> entry:map.entrySet()){
    System.err.println(entry.getKey()+"\t"+entry.getValue());
}
```

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Right, what java code?

Comment: I have metioned the code in edit

Comment: You actually posted a nearly-unreadable image of code. You didn't post code.

Comment: Map<String,String> map = System.getenv();

Comment: Then I just printed the contents of map

Comment: Please replace your images with copied text (indented four spaces so it appears as a formatted code block).  Images cannot be searched or indexed, are difficult to see on mobile devices, and are useless to sight impaired users.

Comment: I have made necessary changes!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/28344/path-env-variable-on-mac-os-x-and-or-eclipse). 
I had to launch eclipse in a different way as mentioned in the post which worked for me.